# bash: how to check double substition failure with special characters?

Tags: bash

I want to do double substitution with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
p1="Alice"
p2="Bob"
p3="Charlie"
p4="David"

map_people()
{
    p=`eval echo "\\${p$1}"`
    if [ -z "$p" ]; then
        echo $1
    else
        echo $p
    fi
}
```

Mostly correct

```
map_people 1
Alice

map_people 5
5

map_people John
John

map_people John-Smith
Smith
```

Except the last one, which I want to return John-Smith. I try a few ways but not quite right yet. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `-` is not a valid character in a variable name, it has a special meaning in parameter expanstion. When you do

```
map_people John-Smith
```

it executes:

```
p=`eval echo "\\${pJohn-Smith}"
```

which is equivalent to:

```
p=`echo ${pJohn-Smith}`
```

The `-` character is used to provide a default value when a variable isn't set. So what this means is to set `p` to the value of `$pJohn` if it's set, or `Smith` if it's not. So when there's no variable `$pJohn`, this does `p=Smith`, and then `echo $p` prints that.

It's not possible to escape the `-` to get it to be treated literally. `-` is not allowed in variable names, so you get an error if you try that. You simply can't try to use arbitrary input as part of a variable name. You could try removing any non-alphanumeric characters from `$1` before using it.

Whenever you find yourself using numbered variables like `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, etc. it's a sure sign that you should be using an array instead.